# Sencha - div does not scroll

Tags: html, extjs, scroll

I modified the code like [this](http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.0.0/demos/Ext.Container.tpl/viewer.html) and I added some items, because I'd like to get a div with scroll, but it does not work in Sencha!
Any suggest?
Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
/*global Ext:false */
Ext.application({
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            fullscreen: true,
            styleHtmlContent: true,
            data: [{
                fname: 'Stratton',
                lname: 'Sclavos',
                role: 'Executive Chairman'
            }, 
etc. ], 
                tpl: '<div style="overflow: auto; overflow-y: auto;"><tpl for="."><div><strong>{lname}</strong>, {fname} <em class="muted">({role})</em></div></tpl></div>'
            }); // create()
        } // launch
    }); // application()
```

Comment: Are you talking about Sencha Touch? If so, you should add a 'sencha-touch' tag to your question... And for the next time, you should also say it explicitly in the question or title.

Answer (score 3):

Add:

```
scrollable : {
    direction     : 'vertical'
},
```

Like this:

```
/*global Ext:false */
Ext.application({
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            fullscreen: true,
            styleHtmlContent: true,
            scrollable : {
                direction     : 'vertical'
            },
            data: [{
                fname: 'Stratton',
                lname: 'Sclavos',
                role: 'Executive Chairman'
            }, 
etc. ], 
                tpl: '<div style="overflow: auto; overflow-y: auto;"><tpl for="."><div><strong>{lname}</strong>, {fname} <em class="muted">({role})</em></div></tpl></div>'
            }); // create()
        } // launch
    }); // application()
```

Comment: @ImanOdor would you mind accepting the answer in that case?:)